# Unknown variable for Python typehint

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pep

I have a wrapper function, what should I put as the return value if the variable to be returned is unknown?

```
def try_catch_in_loop(func_to_call: callable, *args):
    for attempt in range(NUM_RETRYS + 1):
        try:
            if attempt < NUM_RETRYS:
                return func_to_call(*args)
            else:
                raise RunTimeError("Err msg")
        except gspread.exceptions.APIError:
            request_limit_error()
```

Specifically looking what to put at the end of the function call ie:

`def try_catch_in_loop(...) -> {What do I put here}:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining `func_to_call` to be a [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) that returns some [`Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) type, you can then say that `try_catch_in_loop` will also return that type.  You would express this using a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

return_type = TypeVar("return_type")

def try_catch_in_loop(func_to_call: Callable[..., return_type], *args) -> return_type:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the `Any` type. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any

Comment: Using `Any` essentially disables type checking locally and defeats the purpose of using type annotations. In contrast, the annotation suggested in the accepted answer indeed guarantees proper type consistency.